# Drupal 7 / Views mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have tried searching but didn't find a good answer matching my case.

I have a database structure managed by drupal. I wish to use that structure into another context on the same server making a php file that makes a sql query to the db and fetch the results into a page not managed by drupal (in this specific case drupal is more like a user interface for the content manager than a real CMS for website design).

I've installed views and setup the options and the criteria to extract data from the fields i require for my php script.

The preview show me exactly the field i'm asking and the query is shown like this:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node'       AS field_data_field_descrizione_node_entity_type, 'node' AS  field_data_field_web_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_logo_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.type IN  ('collaborazioni')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

I manage to make a connection to the exact same server and db with a php script but when i send the query i recive this mysql_error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '} node WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND     (node.type IN ('collaborazioni')) )) ' at line 3
```

I really don't know what's wrong, maybe you can help me figure this out? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: try as WHERE node.type IN  ('collaborazioni')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal uses table aliases in the views preview query. It gets replaced before the actual query is sent to the database. The alias part is `{node}`, which points to the node table in database, but adds the table prefix that you entered during site installation. If you did not use a database prefix then just remove the `{node}` part of the query. If you did, then you should replace the `{node}` with `prefix_node`.

So without prefix it should be:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node'       AS field_data_field_descrizione_node_entity_type, 'node' AS  field_data_field_web_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_logo_node_entity_type
FROM 
node
WHERE (( (node.type IN  ('collaborazioni')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

And with prefix it should be (replace the "prefix" part of the query with the prefix you used of course):

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node'       AS field_data_field_descrizione_node_entity_type, 'node' AS  field_data_field_web_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_logo_node_entity_type
FROM 
prefix_node node
WHERE (( (node.type IN  ('collaborazioni')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```